# JLabel not Moving or Appearing

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I am trying to make a fade out transition my moving a JLabel with a transparent gradient so it starts fading out from the bottom up. This will be activated by a button that when pressed, will begin the transition by creating a label with the transparent gradient image and changing its position using a for loop. However, whenever I click the button, it appears to do nothing and it does not load the image nor the animation.
This is the image I am trying to load https://i.stack.imgur.com/81hh0.jpg

```
 setSize(800, 600);  
 setLayout(null);
 setResizable(false);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    
 // Start Menu Background
 ImageIcon start_menu_img = new ImageIcon("src/img/menu_background.png");
 JLabel start_menu = new JLabel("", start_menu_img, JLabel.CENTER);
 start_menu.setBounds(0,0,800,600);

 // Start Button
 start = new JButton(new ImageIcon("src/img/start.png"));
 start.setBounds(240,327,320,100);
 start.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

 // Sets main menu label and adds it to the frame
 start.addActionListener(this);

 JLabel main_menu = new JLabel();
 main_menu.setBounds(getBounds());
 main_menu.add(start);
 main_menu.add(start_menu);
 add(main_menu);


@Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == start) {

      try {
        AudioInputStream select = getAudioFile("select.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(select);  
        clip.start();

        Thread.sleep(500);

        ImageIcon transition_ImageIcon = new ImageIcon("src/img/transition.png");
        JLabel transition = new JLabel();
        transition.setIcon(transition_ImageIcon);
        transition.setBounds(0,600,800,1800);
        add(transition);
        
        for(int i = 600; i > -1200; i--) {
          transition.setBounds(0, i, 800, 1800);
          Thread.sleep(1);
        }

      } catch (Exception e1) {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should never be calling Thread.sleep in an actionPerformed method. This will cause the GUI thread to sleep. And the GUI thread is only able to execute a repaint AFTER your actionPerformed method has exited (Swing is single threaded). You will want to checkout java.swing.Timer

Comment: And you definitely shouldn't be trying to play an audio file in the gui thread either. `SwingWorker` will be your friend. Also, shouldn't you be doing a fade *without* moving the component?

Comment: Also, as a note of advice: If the purpose of what you are doing is to improve your programming skills (ie not a requirement of your job) IMHO learning CSS 3 transitions may be far more useful for you.

Comment: @ControlAltDel would Swing support CSS transitions?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: @g00se No, I don't believe Swing will ever support CSS transitions. More thoroughly stated, I think that putting one's energy into improving one's CSS (and JS) skills for doing animations in HTML 5 is more useful than working on improving Swing skills. This is just my opinion

Comment: Didn't think so - just checking ;)